# Pytesseract fails to recognize digits from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

Pytesseract fails to recognize digits `6` and `8`. It recognizes

- `6` as `5` and
- `5` as `5`,
- `3` as `8` and
- `8` as `8`,
- `Oct` as `0c:` or `0::` and
- `Wed` as `Men`.

The script used:

```
config= "-c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890.:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -psm 3 -oem 0"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=config)
```

Tried also using the different psm number from 1-12 but no luck. Increasing contrast results in more numbers not recognized:

```
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(im, kernel)#,iterations = 1)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(dilation, config=config)
```

Raw data:

[image: How the raw data looks like]

After running the script:

[image: After running the script]

After running new script:

[image: After running new script]

Comment: No, resize the image. Use [`cv.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d). Check to see how many pixels tall your uppercase letters are, then compute how much to scale the image to make them around 50 pixels tall.

Answer (score 2):

Some preprocessing to clean/smooth the image before throwing it into Pytesseract can help. Specifically, morphological operations to close small holes and remove noise can enhance the image. Also applying sharpening filters may help as well. Also adjusting the kernel size or type may help. I believe `--psm 6` is the best here since the image is a single uniform block of text. Here's what I get after a simple morph close

[image]

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png',0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
result = 255 - close

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hi @nathancy, not sure why my results aren't the same. Copied the exact codes but the results are as follows, will attach the photo in the question:                                                                                             in the Date Total mrm morn mu 0:: Va( am New Aunt Depart 705211 ‘Mvl rm Rooms ‘M41 Trot Room Revenu: Avg Rate
25 520 Had 104 1 103 3 100 — — — — 100 97 95 3 3 3 9 147 77 3 049 25
25 520 TM 104 1 103 3 100 — — — — 100 97 95 3 3 3 9 147 77 3 049 25
27 520 FM 104 1 103 3 100 — — — 1 101 90 97 2 2 2 5 203 23 3 101 52
2

Comment: If you convert jpg to png, you already have losses that cannot be recovered by converting to png.